# How to add custom form field in registration form using profile builder plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add some custom input field in registration form in registration page(frontend side) using profile builder plugin in wordpress(PHP). But I can't add any field(form field) in the form. I am using profile builder plugin short code [wppb-register]. If any body has solution please help with steps.

Comment: Please browse the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). StackOverflow is for coding-related questions. If you are having issues with a plugin, then you are better to contact their support or ask on the support forum on their plugin page.